# Counting number of clicks of a button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to count the number of clicks of a button?

```
var count = 0;

if(getElementbyId("generateid").clicked)
{
count++;
return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use .onclick over the button object:

```
var button = document.getElementById('yourButton'), count = 0;
button.onclick = function(){ ++count; };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the counter as member of the HTMLElement instance.

```
var el = document.getElementById('myElem');

el.onclick = function() {
  if(!this.clickCount) this.clickCount = 0;
  this.clickCount++;
}
```